# Adding data from multiple columns from different tables

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables, TABLE1

```
ID1     ID2 Count1  Count2  Count3
aaaaa   bbbbb   1     1      0
ccccc   dddd    2     2      0 
eeee    fffff   3     3      0
gggg    hhhh    4     4      0
```

and Table2

```
ID1     ID2 Count1  Count2  Count3
bbbbb   aaaaa   5       5   5
dddd    ccccc   4       4   4
fffff   eeee    3       3   3
aaaaaa  gggg    2       2   2
```

Now I want to add the count1 and count3 and call it a new count4 and the condition is where table1.id1 = table2.id2 and table2.id1 = table1.id2.

I am aware that a case when has to be used but I am not sure about the join.

The final table should be like this

```
ID1     ID2 Count4  Count2  Count3
aaaaa   bbbbb   6      1    0
ccccc   dddd    6      2    0
eeee    fffff   6      3    0
gggg    hhhh    4      4    0
```

There could be other rows and whose count3 > 0 in table 1

Comment: there is no row in table1 whose count3>0

Comment: That's just a part of the table. there could be some other rows tooo

Comment: then why your output data is showing rows with count3=0

Answer (score 0):

You must use INNER JOIN to join these two tables and use arithmetic operations to perform a sum:

> SELECT (t1.count1 + t2.count3) AS count4, t1.count1, t1.count3  FROM
>   table1 as t1 INNER JOIN table2 as t2 WHERE t1.id2 = t2.id

References: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html
and : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

The sum of the count1 depending on the ids are a bit complicated in this case, so you may need to first get the count using left join and group by and finally do a join of table1 to the result something as

```
select
t1.ID1,
t1.ID2,
coalesce(x.Count1,t1.Count1) as Count4,
t1.Count2,
t1.Count3
from table1 t1 
left join (
  select
  x1.ID1,
  sum(x1.Count1+x2.Count1) as Count1
  from table1 x1
  left join Table2 x2 on x1.ID1 = x2.ID2 and x1.ID2=x2.ID1
  group by x1.ID1
)x on x.ID1 = t1.ID1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c0c6d/3